# CYCLIC ERROR: No response from server on port 3000 for nest.js app

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, nest, cyclic

I'm trying to host nestjs rest api on cyclic and getting this error could not find anything about it

Here relevant package.json

```
 {
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "node dist/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "npx nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "npx nest start --debug",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  ........ 
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  }
}
```

here is main.ts file

```
 import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { CorsOptions } from '@nestjs/common/interfaces/external/cors-options.interface';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const corsOptions: CorsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    methods: '*',
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
  };

  app.enableCors(corsOptions);

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

I have hosted other project with same set up without any problem
here the whole [project link](https://github.com/vindexTOS/olm-server)

I attempted to transfer the business logic into another project, but encountered issues. I tried setting the output route as both "/dist" and "/" on the cyclic dashboard. All the environmental variables are configured on Cyclic, and I removed the "env" entry from the gitignore. I built an app, pushed the pre-made "dist" file, and hardcoded the port to 5025, but it still returns a "3000" port not responding error.